# How to toggle username in the nav

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Goal:
When you log in, you should be able to see your username in the nav section in relation to many different menu links with `localStorage`.

However, when you are not logged in, the username should not be visible.

Problem:
How do I implement it?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwt-authentication-example-jjttby?file=App/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement in your element:

```
Hello{user.username ? ' ' + user.username : ''}!
```

assuming user.username is `foo` or `null`:

- foo: `Hello foo!`
- null: `Hello!`